Implicit and explicit Finite Difference method (FDM)
I am trying to understand about implicit and explicit finite difference method (FDM). What I understand so far is that implicit scheme means your are converting a PDE into matrix in the form $Ax =b$ and explicit scheme means that you're not converting it into matrix form and solving it without converting into a matrix. It would be great help if someone can explain this with an example. The reason for asking this question is because there are multiple ways to convert a differential into equation like forward difference, backward difference, central difference. Which one is to be used in which case?

Is FDM = Finite Difference Method? Different problems will call for different schemes (though I like implicit schemes better, as they're conditionally stable).

Thank you @SeanRoberson for the response. I used to thought that FDM means converting PDE in the form Ax = b. But while searching internet, I realized that FDM is of various types.

You need to spell out what your definition of FDM is and from where it comes from. Edit the original post to do this. Also, finite differences doesn't always result in linear equations.

I have already edited the question. FDM here means finite difference method.

Implicit vs. explicit is not about having a matrix form or not, it is about having to solve an equation for the new values or not.
